# Problems when applying node.js/OSC code to github

Tags: node.js, github, socket.io, osc

New to Node.js & socket.io but after a few days of scouring the internet for answers I finally need to ask for help. The code below runs in Brackets with no issue and I can connect it to Max7 to use OSC. However, when I try to commit it to github it no longer works. I'm assuming it has to do with the localhost aspect but I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html> <head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>

<hr />

Received from an OSC app/device at : <div id="status"></div>

<hr />

<script src="http://localhost:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
   socket = io.connect('0.0.0.0', { port: 8081, rememberTransport: 
false});
   console.log('oi');
   socket.on('connect', function() {

        socket.emit('config',
            {
                server: {
                    port: 3333,
                     host: '0.0.0.0'
            },
            client: {
                port: 3334,
                host: '0.0.0.0'
            }
        }
    );
});

socket.on('message', function(obj) {
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = obj[0];
    console.log(obj);
    });
</script>

<button onclick="socket.emit('message', '/fLeft');">Send OSC 
message</button>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: "It no longer works" doesn't give us any information about the problem. What actually happens? And what are the steps to reproduce the problem? This is just an HTML file; how and where does it get used (and "not work") once you commit it to github?

Comment: Ah sorry you're right. I am trying to connect via socket.io to send OSC messages to Max7 on my computer. However, I can only get the code to work through the localhost 127.0.0.1 ip and by using brackets to run the html code. What am I failing to incorporate into my code when I want to upload it to github to have other devices such as my phone be able to push the button and then send the OSC message to Max7 on my computer?

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like your question is more like "how do I host my html file on the web." That doesn't really have anything to do with github unless I'm missing something. This question is probably going to be closed, because it's not about a specific problem. From here, I suggest researching Web hosting. There are lots of hosting providers that will host your html file for free. If you run into a specific problem, you can always start a new question.

Comment: You can start by hosting this file on a web server running on your own computer, which will let any device on your local network access it. That's typically how Web developers do most of their work. Once everything is running correctly, then they deploy to a hosting provider.